# how to call below function in php array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to use this within a class. My compare function is called compare. In a class I would call the function using $this->compare. But, I cannot figure out how to call the class function within usort.

I have tried:

```
usort($array, this->compare);
usort($array, "this->compare");
usort($array, this->"compare");
usort($array, compare);
usort($array, "compare");
```

Here is function:

```
function compare($x, $y)
{
 if ( $x[0] == $y[0] )
  return 0;
 else if ( $x[0] < $y[0] )
  return -1;
 else
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
usort($array, array($this, 'compare'));
```

Documented here: <s>`http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback`</s>(dead link)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
usort($array, array($this, 'compare'))
```

[See PHP's documentation on the callback type](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback).

Answer (score 1):

You do it like this

```
usort($a, array("InstanceName", "Method"));
```

You can also send in the instance if you have it, so you can send in $this

```
usort($a, array($this, "Method"));
```

A larger code example is in the [usort documentation](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
usort($array, array($this, "compare"));
```

See: [PHP Manual](http://de.php.net/callback)